# Drupal 7 force active menu item

Tags: php, menu, drupal-7

I got a page where I link to in the menu bar. On this page there is a custom module. On this page there are items from anothor database where the user can click on. When they click on it they go to another page with more information.
When they are on the second page there is no active button in the menu bar. On the second page I also have a custom module.

How can u force a button in the menu bar to have the .active class or in another way so that it haves the active lay-out button.

I use Drupal 7.

Comment: The question is better suited for http://drupal.stackexchange.com/ :)

Answer (score 0):

I used the context module to solve this.